# Is the set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to a subset of $\mathbb N$ (and vice versa) countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets of functions, let's call them $X$ and $Y$.  $X$ maps $\mathbb N$ to $\{1,2, \ldots , k\}$ and $Y$ does the reverse.  I believe both are unaccountable but am unsure of my answer.  My reasoning is as follows.

$X$ isn't countable because you have an infinite number of inputs with a fixed number of outputs for each function, meaning eventually two different inputs will have to map to the same output.  $Y$ can be shown to be uncountable using Cantor's diagonal method.  Are my answers - and the methods that led me to them - correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is uncountable for all $k\ne 1$. This can be shown because there exists a subset of $A=\{f: N \to {1, 2, \ldots, k}\}$ that can be mapped to the $k$-ary representations of numbers between zero and one, which are countable. Cantor's diagonal argument can be used in this case.

$Y$ is *countable*. Note that this is simply a generalization to the proof that ordered pairs $(a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{N})$ are countable, which is key to the proof of the countability of the rationals. That particular case has $k=2$. Cantor's diagonal argument does not apply, since if we tried, we would run out of numbers in the domain.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for saying X is uncountable.  Could you explain it more thoroughly or in another way?

And for Y, If you ran out of numbers for a particular function couldn't you just resume where you left off with the next function?

Comment: For example, let $k=10$. Then we take a function $f \in X$ and we convert it to a real number $0.f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots$, where each digit is $f$ applied to its place value. Since each real number has at least one $f$ that maps to it in this way, we have an surjective mapping from $X$ to $[0,1)$, which proves uncountability.

Comment: In response to your second part, note that Cantor's diagonal argument first assumes that an enumeration (list) of such functions is possible, then shows a contradiction by finding a new function that cannot be a member of the list. It accomplishes this by selecting the sequence $a_1 \ne f_1(1)$, $a_2 \ne f_2(2)$, $a_n \ne f_n(n)$. But since $n \le k$ in this situation, we cannot continue this indefinitely, so there is no guarantee that our new function will not be in the list.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanations. I struggle with the material but what you have said helps.